# How can I format a JSON with MongoDB to be use with Highcharts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, highcharts

This is my end-point:

I have a JSON that look like this:

```
{
        "_id": "5d30c48e5fb507250bb5",
        "user": "5d2f594180064d82c47c",
        "department_director": "Director 1",
        "account_manager": "Account Manager 1",
        "fronter": "Fronter 2",
        "closer": "Closer 1",
        "order_number": "EDVRV20202020202",
        "business_name": "Business Name 3",
        "business_website": "www.businessname3.com",
        "client_name": "Client 3",
        "client_phone": 9090909090,
        "client_email": "email1@company.com",
        "type_of_service": "Other",
        "management_fee": 599,  //I will use this objects
        "sales_date": "2017-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "cancellation_date": "2018-04-23T00:00:00.000Z", // I will use this object,
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "Florida",
        "cancellation_reason": "Business Closed",
    },
```

And, I want to plot the following graph using type_of_service as a legend, cancellation_date as a x-axis and management_fee and a y_axi.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Highcharts needs to have this data format for line type series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data